# Inno Setup reg edits .. best way

Tags: inno-setup, registry

I'm just getting up with inno setup and my question is more about install strategy ..

Is there an advantage to copying a reg file to the user's machine and then running it rather than have inno create all the reg edits I need (quite a few of them)

Considerations:

1. a reg file approach would allow for an install repair option for the user.
2. a reg file approach would be easier to code and edit.
3. a reg file approach might have problems with UAC.
4. a reg file approach would require, likely a separate uninstall process to remove reg keys `(-regfile,reg)`.

Any thoughts out there?  Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no advantage but there are downsides.

In response to your points:

1. So does inno, but with more control.
2. You can create it by an export, but it's no easier to edit, it's still just a text line for each entry.
3. It shouldn't do as it runs with full access of the user.
4. Correct. Inno does all this automatically as part of its uninstall process if it created the keys, once again with far more control.

If you have a reg file, you can import it into an Inno file using ISTool.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I didn't know ISTool could convert reg files to Inno Setup commands. Sweet! I'm still considering dropping a reg file or two for install repairs and user setups. Sometimes my customers have employee turnovers with new user accounts and it would be much easier to run a reg file than an install process. Thanks again.

Comment: If it's per user, it should be done by your app if they're not found for exactly that reason.